# joining three queries from same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have to join 3 queries from same table. I have tried this code:

```
SELECT t1.`board`
      ,t1.`price`
      ,t2.`price`
      ,t3.`price`
  from boardtype t1
  RIGHT JOIN(SELECT `price`
      from boardtype
      WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='single')
  t2 on t1.`board` = t2.`board`
  RIGHT JOIN(
      SELECT 
      `price`
      from boardtype 
      WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='double'
  ) t3 on t1.`board` = t3.`board`
WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='triple'
ORDER by id
```

Simply say I'm trying to join these three queries:

```
SELECT `board`,`price` FROM boardtype WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='single'
SELECT `board`,`price` FROM boardtype WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='double'
SELECT `board`,`price` FROM boardtype WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='triple'
```

I don't know where I made mistake.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What's your schema? More info is helpful.

Comment: i try to join these queries SELECT `board`,`price` FROM boardtype WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='single'                                                
SELECT `board`,`price` FROM boardtype WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='double'
SELECT `board`,`price` FROM boardtype WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='triple'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no `board` in your subselects, and yet you write the `ON` clauses using them.

Add the `board` to the subselects:

```
SELECT t1.`board`
      ,t1.`price`
      ,t2.`price`
      ,t3.`price`
  from boardtype t1
  RIGHT JOIN
      (SELECT `price`, `board`
      from boardtype
      WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='single') t2 on t1.`board` = t2.`board`
  RIGHT JOIN(
      SELECT `price`, `board`
      from boardtype
      WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='double') t3 on t1.`board` = t3.`board`
WHERE `acnonac`='ac' AND `roomtype`='triple'
ORDER by id
```

Comment: wow thank you so much sir.. im trying since 2 hours.. thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

> **Maybe it was more efficient**

```
SELECT `boardtype`.`board`
      ,`boardtype`.`price`
  from `boardtype` WHERE `boardtype`.`acnonac`='ac' AND `boardtype`.`roomtype` IN ('single', 'double', 'triple')
```

> **Thanks**